# What is the best way to synchronize small amounts of data between Mac and iOS versions of an app?

Tags: ios, macos, synchronization

I am developing a small and open-source document viewer for OS X and iOS which should synchronize the list of opened tabs that view PDF files from the iCloud drive. I thought about storing this information in the iCloud drive as well, however it seems that the iCloud drive only updates in very unpredictable and slow ways (cf. [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/150962/force-icloud-drive-to-sync-under-yosemite)). Are there some alternatives that don't require setting up a server of my own?

Comment: So both OS X and iOS apps use the same Ubiquity Containers ID?

Comment: @user523234 That is necessary to access the same directory in iCloud drive? Is that possible in the first place?

Comment: I have worked with two different iOS apps.  But I have not worked with OS X and iOS apps.  I am certain that will work the same.  Search around: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567075/icloud-sync-core-data-between-ios-and-osx?rq=1

Comment: @user523234 How quickly does it do the synchronization?

Comment: Yeah, that was your original question.  We have no control.  Sometimes it is immediate.

Comment: @user523234 What would be an immediate alternative?

Comment: I might be wrong on this:  MS Onedrive, Google drive, Dropbox, etc probably will serve what you need.  Since they are not iOS native frameworks, they do not have the kind of local container as in iCloud.